# suddenly, mongoose started to return null to all queries

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

Until yesterday, mongoose was working normal, but, at sudden, all my queries of local host is returning null even when it works at MongoDB shell.

```
mongodb config:
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const fs = require('fs')

async function connect_database() {
    try {
        const promise = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Amazon_products',
            { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
        await promise
        console.log("connected to database")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("database error:" + error)
    }

}
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
connect_database()

const prods_schema = mongoose.Schema({
    brand: String,
    title: String,
    url: String,
    rating: Number,
    price: Number,
    image: String,
})

const products = mongoose.model('Product_info', prods_schema, 'Product_info')
////query
products.find().exec(
    (res)=>{console.log(res)}

)
//returns null
```

i tried to reinstall mongodb, it didn't work, what can i do???

Comment: Did you look at DB to make sure it's all ok with values?

Comment: Yes, i can query with no problems in the shell and Compass works normally

Comment: At least you didn't wait till connect_database() finish because it's async.

Comment: ow, so that was the problem